# Bad python path in bash script from crontab

Tags: python, cron

I would like to use the python3 executable when I use it from crontab as manual launch (ssh session).

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHONPATH="$(which python3)"
echo $PYTHONPATH

python3 test.py
```

result from ssh command line, launched manually

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

result in log file from crontab -e

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

I would like the script launched by the crontab, uses */usr/local/bin/python3* executable instead of */usr/bin/python3*

OR
if it's not possible, use the dependencies of my code available for */usr/bin/python3*

How can I achieve this ? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Are you running the program as root in cron? You could run as a non-root user, which is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: I'm using this in docker container and when I try manually, I'm connected as root.

Answer (score 0):

the python inside the docker container will not necessarily have the same path. If you want all the modules installed on your VM python3, create a requirements.txt file using `pip freeze > requirements.txe` and COPY this file as part of your Dockerfile and install it while building the image `pip install -r requirements.txt`